# Text manipulation in Spark and Scala

Tags: scala, text, apache-spark

This is my data:

```
review/text: The product picture and part number match, but they together do not math the description.

review/text: A necessity for the Garmin. Used the adapter to power the unit on my motorcycle. Works like a charm.

review/text: This power supply did the job and got my computer back online in a hurry.

review/text: Not only did the supply work. it was easy to install, a lot quieter than the PowMax that fried.

review/text: This is an awesome power supply that was extremely easy to install. 

review/text: I had my doubts since best buy would end up charging me $60. at the time I bought my camera for the card and the cable.

review/text: Amazing... Installed the board, and that's it, no driver needed. Work great, no error messages.
```

and I've tried:

```
import org.apache.spark.{SparkContext, SparkConf}

object test12 {
  def filterfunc(s: String): Array[((String))] = {
    s.split( """\.""") 
      .map(_.split(" ")
      .filter(_.nonEmpty)
      .map(_.replaceAll( """\W""", "")
      .toLowerCase)
      .filter(_.nonEmpty)
      .flatMap(x=>x)
  }

  def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
    val conf1 = new SparkConf().setAppName("pre2").setMaster("local")
    val sc = new SparkContext(conf1)
    val rdd = sc.textFile("data/2012/2012.txt")
    val stopWords = sc.broadcast(List[String]("reviewtext", "a", "about", "above", "according", "accordingly", "across", "actually",...)

    var grouped_doc_words = rdd.flatMap({ (line) =>
      val words = line.map(filterfunc).filter(word_filter.value))
      words.map(w => {
        (line.hashCode(), w)
      })
    }).groupByKey()

  }
}
```

and I want to generate this output :

```
doc1: product picture number match together not math description. 
doc2: necessity garmin. adapter power unit my motorcycle. works like charm.
doc3: power supply job computer online hurry.
doc4: not supply work. easy install quieter powmax fried.
...
```

some exception: 1- (not , n't , non , none) not to be emitted 2- all dot (.) symbols must be held

my above code doesn't work very well.

Comment: Can you explain what you're hoping to do? Are you trying to filter out a set of words, but keeping all words that end with a period?

Comment: I believe he is trying to prepare his text for sentiment analysis, so he needs to tokenize it to "improve performance"

Comment: @ohruunuruus, It is not important which word must be filtered out , i want an output like above.

Comment: @eliasah , Yes it is for sentiment analysis.

Comment: What is it about your output you want? As far as I can tell, all you've done to produce that output is filter out some words, and replace "review/text:" with "docN:". Please state the requirements of the output. 1) Filter words. 2) Something about periods. 3) Apparently tokenization, though your output does not necessarily imply tokenization.

Comment: 1- first of all split by "." 2-tokenizing 3- convert to lowercase 3-remove special chars 4- filtering stop words

Comment: If i understand what u are trying to do you should not have to group anything. You start with lines don't flatMap them. Notice that not only grouping is really costly u can't hope to group lines in the same order.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why not just sth like this:

This way you don't need any grouping or flatMapping.

**EDIT:**

I was writing this by hand and indeed there was some little bugs but i hoped idea was clear. Here is tested code:

```scala
def processLine(s: String, stopWords: Set[String]): List[String] = {
    s.toLowerCase()
      .replaceAll(""""[^a-zA-Z\.]""", "")
      .replaceAll("""\.""", " .")
      .split("\\s+")
      .filter(!stopWords.contains(_))
      .toList
  }

  def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
    val conf1 = new SparkConf().setAppName("pre2").setMaster("local")
    val sc = new SparkContext(conf1)
    val rdd = sc.parallelize(
      List(
        "The product picture and part number match, but they together do not math the description.",
        "A necessity for the Garmin. Used the adapter to power the unit on my motorcycle. Works like a charm.",
        "This power supply did the job and got my computer back online in a hurry."
      )
    )
    val stopWords = sc.broadcast(
      Set("reviewtext", "a", "about", "above",
        "according", "accordingly",
        "across", "actually", "..."))
    val grouped_doc_words = rdd.map(processLine(_, stopWords.value))
    grouped_doc_words.collect().foreach(p => println(p))
  }
```

This as result gives you:

```
List(the, product, picture, and, part, number, match,, but, they, together, do, not, math, the, description, .)
List(necessity, for, the, garmin, ., used, the, adapter, to, power, the, unit, on, my, motorcycle, ., works, like, charm, .)
List(this, power, supply, did, the, job, and, got, my, computer, back, online, in, hurry, .)
```

Now if you want string not list just do:

```
grouped_doc_words.map(_.mkString(" "))
```

Answer (score -1):

I think there is a bug at marked line:

```
var grouped_doc_words = rdd.flatMap({ (line) =>
  val words = line.map(filterfunc).filter(word_filter.value)) // **
  words.map(w => {
    (line.hashCode(), w)
  })
}).groupByKey()
```

Here:

```
line.map(filterfunc)
```

should be:

```
filterfunc(line)
```

Explanation:

`line` is a String. `map` runs over a collection of items. When you do `line.map(...)` it basically runs the passed function on each `Char` - not something that you want.

```
scala> val line2 = "This is a long string"
line2: String = This is a long string

scala> line2.map(_.length)
<console>:13: error: value length is not a member of Char
              line2.map(_.length)
```

Additionally, I don't know what are you using this in filterfunction:

```
.map(_.replaceAll( """\W""", "")
```

I am not able to run spark-shell properly at my end. Can you please update if these fix your problem?

Comment: thanks for your reply , but they both (line.map(filterfunc) ) and (filterfunc(line)) are the same.

Comment: How can they be same? A `String` is equivalent of `Array[Char]` and hence the function passed in `map` i.e. `filterfunc` will get applied to the items which are `Char` - I assume it will cry out in compilation. Can you please explain this to me? baffled over this. Thanks.

Comment: I have added an interaction on spark-shell in the answer (Explanation section). It also is in resonance to my understanding.